# need a data structure to store box size details and an algorithm to find the smallest box that is bigger than a given object

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

we are looking for a data structure which stores and sorts boxes which have two attributes:
 1. height
 2. side (square base)

the boxes are meant to store objects which have the same attributes:
 1. height
 2. side (square base)

The structure should be able to and do the following:

1. InsertBox (height, side) - insert a box with the given attributes from the 
   structure.
2. RemoveBox (height, side) - remove a box with the given attributes from the
   structure.
3. GetBox (height, side) - return the minimum volume box which has at least a 
   minimum side and height as given.
4. CheckBox (height, side) - checks if there's any box available for these 
   attributes.

the data structure should be the most efficient as possible.
the time complexity should be measured by the parameters:
 1. height - n
 2. side (square base) - m

I thought that the best way to do it is by RB Tree so in some way the methods above will be in time complexity which is better than (n+m), maybe log(n+m).

Comment: You effectively need two trees; one based on height comparison, the other based on side comparison.

Comment: Shouldn't the complexity be measured in terms of the number of boxes?

Comment: How do you tell when an object fits in a box? A 3-dimensional object with a narrow enough base can be placed so as to exploit the fact that the length of the diagonal connecting the two farthest corners in the box exceeds both the height of the box and the length of the square base.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Perhaps you meant three-dimensional volume of a box, not area. In such case simply change goal function: replace *x * y* with *(x^2 * y)* everywhere in the answer.

Consider each box with side *x* and height *y*. Let's treat them as points on 2D plane instead of boxes with sizes. Then you need a data structure that can add points, remove points, find points, and make a special *GetBox* operation.

The *GetBox* operation asks to find a point in given upper quadrant with minimal product of coordinates. In other words, you have to find a point with minimal *x * y* for which *x >= a* and *y >= b* (*a* and *b* are given in the query). One-dimensional trees like RB tree will **not** help you here.

You need to use a two-dimensional tree with range queries. Any of the following can be used: [Kd tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), etc. These data structures split active points into progressively smaller regions, allowing to prune whole regions at once on query. Your *GetBox* is efficiently a [range query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Range_search) then, which is a natural operation for these trees (k-D tree for instance).

Note that on *GetBox* query you want to get one point with minimal *x * y* instead of simply enumerating all of them. That's why you should maintain index of such point in each node of the tree. In other words, in each node *v* of your tree you should store index of the point within *v*-subtree with minimal product *x * y*.

Speaking of complexity, k-D tree has worst case complexity *O(sqrt(N))* for range queries, where *N* is number of points currently in the tree. All the other operations are likely to take *O(log N)* in worst case (depends on rebalancing scheme, I suppose).

Comment: thank you, but there is a problem with your solution: k-d trees have no rebalance procedure like red black trees, and that will cause the search to have an O(n) complexity after several insertions (in the worst case - the tree will look like a list..). i heard from a friend that he solved this problem with two separate red-black trees, any ideas?

Comment: @fady88: You **can** rebalance k-d trees. For instance you can rebuild your tree completely if you detect that it it badly balanced. There can be other approaches, too. Most likely you won't get an algorithm with good worst-case time guarantees, but it would work fast in practice. RBtrees have balancing scheme deeply inside it: you cannot use them without it. Kd trees do not have one (think of it as of an equivalent for *binary search trees* in multidimensional case).

Comment: i understand what you are saying, but i am asking if we can solve the problem in less than O(n) in IN THE WORST CASE, not in average case.. i started to think that maybe there is no such thing.. do you have any ideas?

Comment: by the way, isn`t that problem, a variation of the "knapsack problem" which is one of several problems who have no efficient solution?

Comment: @fady88: Please read [this article](https://www.cs.duke.edu/~pankaj/publications/papers/bkd-sstd.pdf). At the beginning it states that there are some rebalancing approaches for kd tree which allow to insert and delete elements in *O(log N)* worst case time without hurting query time. However, the paper also states that these approaches are not beneficial in practice: they work worse than heuristical rebalancing (which do not guarantee worst case time complexity).

Comment: @fady88: No, it is not related to knapsack right now. It would be only if you would search for a **subset of boxes** with bounded total volume or length.